# How to remove flutter splash screen status bar's color overlay WITHOUT making it Fullscreen?

Tags: android, flutter

I wanted to make a perfectly blended splash screen WITHOUT it being Fullscreen. By that I mean I want to make a splash screen which its background color blends with the status bar. I was successful in achieving making a splash screen the right way (by that I mean by editing the android `xml` files) and making the status bar color the same as the splash screen's background color but there is this some kind of overlay grey-ish color thingy that shows over the status bar for some fraction of seconds. I can't even capture it in a screen shot. I have tried different methods. The `SystemOverlay` call with `statusBarColor` set to transparent, didn't work, it only changes the app theme's status bar color that renders after the splash screen. I have tried different `parent` attributes for my splash theme (like `Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar` and all other bunch), but still the problem persists. And then i tried to play with style `item` in `styles.xml`. Here are the bunch of items I have tried (Not all at once though).

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Answer this question if you have successfully removed the overlay thing. Please don't give me hope with just a guess or something you haven't tried for yourself. And BELEIVE ME, I have been searching up and down for this and I have only found one person with this question in his/her main question's comment section but this person couldn't get an answer so that is why I posted it as a question. Maybe i have missed it, so if this question is answered elsewhere, please provide me with the link. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the statusbarcolor transparant?

Comment: Yes I have. It doesn't work as i expect it to.

Comment: It should work if you make the statusbarcolor transparant, what doesn't work? Do you have any more information?

Comment: As i said i was able to change the status bar color to the color of my splash screen's background color. What i couldn't do and what i asked for is how to remove that overlay thingy that shows for a fraction of seconds each time the app launches.

Answer (score 0):

In styles.xml:

```
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

And in MainActivity.kt:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

It work for me.